# Getting property in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array that I can't get the value of a property from. 
For example:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
          }
      }
    "data": {
         "2": {
            "id": 2,
          }
      } 
}
```

The number of items in the array is dynamic so I don't use a fixed number when trying to get "id". I use a loop function like this `for(i=0;i<array.data.length;i++)` which then loops through numbers until the number of items is met solving the dynamic number of items problem. But the problem lies when I try to call for `"id"` using `array.data[i].id` to call for the values of "id". All I get is `TypeError: Cannot read property "id" of undefined`

So my question is, how do I get the value of "id"?

PS: Sorry if my format is weird, or sloppy. This is my first post to stackoverflow.

Comment: This is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: show your actual and valid input structure

Comment: the json data looks not well formatted: 5 opening curly braces and 2 closing ones

Comment: your data-format looks weird. to your problem: `{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
}` and `for(i=0;i<array.data.length;i++)` there's no `array.data[0]`

Comment: Yes, my format was wrong, I typed it myself and completely messed it up. Very sorry. However, I believe I corrected it.

Comment: Your data-format is still weird. Properly formatted, but it has a weird structure. And you should debug the resulting object because I'm pretty sure it is not what you expect. and there's still no index `0` in `array.data`, so `array.data[0].id` is trying to access the `id` of a non-existing value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use `var key in array`?

It's like so:

```
for(var key in array){
  var myData = array[key];

  console.log(myData.id); // should return your data object
}
```

-- in your case you might need a double one

```
//access the array with the sub-arrays:
for(var key in array){
  var myData = array[key];

  //access the data sub-array
  for(var dataKey in myData){
    var id = myData[dataKey].id
  }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very, very broken. First off, let's solve your question with working JSON.

```
[
    {
        "1": {
            "id": 1
         }
      },
    {
         "2": {
            "id": 2
          }
      } 
]
```

Seeing as this is useless, weirdly done data, you could find the id of a certain item by doing:

```
arr[n][n+1]
```

I still have no idea what you are asking, what you are trying to do, or how this is useful.